# Android setting up androidTestCompile

Tags: android, junit, android-testing

I am trying to setup up androidTests in an existing project.

Following the official guide by Google I added following dependencies:

```
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2'
    androidTestCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.5.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
```

The first problem was, that there were multiple confilicting files (duplicates) within the APK:

```
packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '.readme'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/plexus/components.xml'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
        pickFirst 'licenses/thoughtworks.TXT'
        pickFirst 'licenses/javolution.license.TXT'
        pickFirst 'licenses/extreme.indiana.edu.license.TXT'
        pickFirst 'org/apache/maven/project/pom-4.0.0.xml'
        pickFirst 'org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-bootstrap.xml'
        pickFirst 'org/cyberneko/html/res/HTMLlat1.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/cyberneko/html/res/HTMLsymbol.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/cyberneko/html/res/XMLbuiltin.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/cyberneko/html/res/HTMLspecial.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/cyberneko/html/res/ErrorMessages_ja.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/cyberneko/html/res/ErrorMessages.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/cyberneko/html/res/ErrorMessages_ja.txt'
        pickFirst 'org/cyberneko/html/res/ErrorMessages.txt'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
```

After excluding the duplicates, I ended up with ~1700 warning about classes, superclasses and interface which chould not be found, along with the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForMediadeDebugAndroidTest'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

I really don't know at which parts to further look at,to make tests work.

EDIT: Here are the [Gradle Logs](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/4ndro1d/92c7f210fa6dddf48feb63a75529eaad/raw/4de36bd98e274b7726d03fd539306649b30f4555/Gradle%2520Log)

Comment: Please share the logs from **Gradle Console**.

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/4ndro1d/92c7f210fa6dddf48feb63a75529eaad/raw/4de36bd98e274b7726d03fd539306649b30f4555/Gradle%2520Log hope this link works

Comment: The logs you posted don't seem to have any *error*. It seems you are running tests with ProGuard on? Why would you do that while running tests?

Comment: I don't know.  The debug buildType is using `proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.txt', 'proguard-debug.txt'` - as far as I know the debug buildtype is the one used for testing?

Comment: Removing that line may fix it.

Comment: Sadly not, but the number of warnings was reduced to 191: https://gist.github.com/4ndro1d/d4b201a08b4920f179c2d2f853ddd08d

Comment: Is `minifyEnalbed` true?

Comment: Yes, and i tried turning it off: https://gist.github.com/4ndro1d/951818620f6449be095c80ea8ebb2461 Seems that the problem is now the duplicate libraries? How can I find out which are duplicated, and how can i prevent this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142040/discussion-between-kamran-ahmed-and-4ndro1d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not run ProGuard while running tests, so you can remove the `proguardFiles` lines and change `minifyEnabled` to **false**.

**EDIT**

To get rid of duplicate dependencies, you need to check the Gradle Console logs to look for the lines about `java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry` to find which classes are being added multiple times.

Once you know which classes are duplicated, you can fix it as explained here: [Fixing ZipException: duplicate entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43470418/1468093)

Comment: How do I know from which dependency the duplicates are produced? Do I need to remove all dependencies and then start adding them again? Is there any better solution?

Comment: You can probably search for the class name you see in the error and find out which dependency it must be coming from...

Comment: That's how I would do it. Usually, you know it when you just add a dependency and it fails to build.